# Internet Explorer BHO check for multi-instance of site

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

I'm working on a project for a client. We are building an internal web portal, and for various (mostly political) reasons have ended up building a BHO for IE8. One of the things t does is make sur that only one instance of the portal can be opened at once. It does this by writing a temp file when the portal is opened. Unfortunately this is not optimal as if IE crashes for any reason then the next time the portal is fired up, the user is left staring at an "unauthorised" message until the stale temp file is removed.
So my question is: is there any way within a BHO to see how many times the same url has been loaded? I mean is there some way to get that information directly from IE?
It's actually a little more complicated than that, given that we need to allow popups etc. But this would be a good start.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can't your BHO delete the file when Internet Explorer is started? Probably the user hasn't opened any site on startup and even if, when loading the portal the file should be created again. (I'm not familiar with BHO's and don't know if they get started with the browser or only when the site is accessed.)

Comment: This is what we have done in the end. Every time a new instance of IE is run, all residing temp files are checked against the current process ids belonging to IE. If a temp file (whose name contains a process id) exists but the corresponding process id does not, it is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want limit browser instances in the current user session you can use a mutex instead of a file. try acquire the mutex at the startup of the BHO (in the SetSite call) with a reasonable timeout, and release again in the final SetSite call.

If the result is WAIT_OBJECT_0 or WAIT_ABANDONED, there is no other BHO instance holding the mutex, while WAIT_ABANDONED occur when another thread crashed while holding the mutex. If the result is WAIT_TIMEOUT, the mutex is already taken by another BHO instance and you should not let the user to use your web site according to your requirement.

But if I am a determined user I can fire up XP Mode and access the web site from there...

Comment: We do not want to limit borwser instances, simply ones that acces the internal portal.

Comment: In the end we redid the temp file solution. There are certain cases when multi-instance is allowed (designed by committee - hell on wheels!) so we use the file to tell use which urls are authorised. Good answer though!