# C++ BHO: Detect the an instance of my extension if already running or not

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

I have an ie extension I wrote in c++ (atl) and the problem is that each time I open a new tab a new instance of my extension is running. I need a way to know whether there's an instance running already or not.

I thought using Mutex:

```
if(!Utils::IsAddonMutexRunning())
{
    aHandle = Utils::CreateAddonMutex();
}
```

And when IE quits:

```
STDMETHODIMP cMyAddon::OnQuit()
{
    if(m_pAddon!=NULL)
    {
        Utils::ReleaseMutex(aHandle);
        m_pAddon->Quit();
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

The problem is that the mutex is never released because onQuit is not getting fired.

Any ideas or other solutions?

Edit:

the problem was when I checked if the mutex exist, thanks to Sheng's answer.

I called if(!Utils::IsAddonMutexRunning()) in the SetSite method:

```
bool  Utils::IsAddonMutexRunning()
{
    HANDLE hMutexOneInstance = ::CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE,
       _T("MYADDONMUTEX2013_____"));

    DWORD retVal = WaitForSingleObject(hMutexOneInstance, 0);
    bool ret = (retVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0  || retVal == WAIT_ABANDONED);



     CloseHandle(hMutexOneInstance);
     return !ret;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer BHO check for multi-instance of site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731396/internet-explorer-bho-check-for-multi-instance-of-site)

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I may be naive, as I've never developed a plugin for IE before, but have you tried the WINAPI equivalent `CreateMutex` with the `Global\` namespace?

When the thread owning the mutex exits, the mutex will be automatically released.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, that gives me the save results, one I create the mutex I can no longer release it. :(

Comment: You may need to fork a thread specific to the plugin to guarantee mutex lifetime.